# Remove printed {} braces when using nested struct and text/template package

Tags: go, struct

I have a line of text that gets printed using the text/template package and a struct that contains 2 strings and nested struct (with a string field).

All my variables get templated correctly in the output except for the nested struct field.

My template is as follows:

```
The username is {{.Name}}, the phone number is {{.Phone}}, and the city is {{.City}}.
```

However it prints like this:

```
The username is {Foo Bar}, the phone number is 5555555, and the city is San Diego.
```

So the struct field is getting templated, but it still has the curly braces on it for some reason. How can I template a nested struct's field without the braces? Thank you.

Comment: The template prints the struct using the default struct format of `{field0 field1 ...}`.  Assuming that `Name` is a struct with fields `First` and `Last`, use `{{.Name.First}} {{.Name.Last}}` to print the name without braces.

Comment: yes that worked... thanks for the fast response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template prints the struct using the default struct format of `{field0 field1 ...}`. Assuming that `Name` is a struct with fields `First` and `Last`, use `{{.Name.First}} {{.Name.Last}}` to print the name without braces.